# Unity and ImgUi drawing to same window with DirectX11

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, directx

So I have a small Win32 C++ application I need to a) show the scene from a free standing Unity 3D application within its window and b) let me draw with ImgUI on top of that view.  My application is a simple one that uses DirectX11 for rendering ImgUI.  I start the Unity application from within this and passes it the window handle, and it happily draws in my window, however it's on top of the ImgUI elements and fills the window totally.  What's the best approach to get them to draw in the order I need, and possibly in a smaller child window?

Edit: I've opened a child window (WS_CHILD), and Unity will happily draw to it, but it's still drawing on top of the ImgUi elements.

Edit2: I've also tried making a second child window.  The Unity child window will always draw on top of this, even when calling `BringWindowToTop(childHwnd)`

Comment: I think in this case it would be better to draw ui on the separate transparent overlay window.

Answer (score 0):

Scouring different forums and other writing on the net it seems like getting the child windows in order is simply not possible. I've gone with drawing separate, transparent windows as indicated by user7860670.